# Hosting Google Apps UI in my app

Tags: google-docs, google-apps

I'm investigating the possibility of re-using Google Apps/Docs in a local hybrid desktop/browser application.

I've been going through the Google documentation on manipulating docs, eg. the Spreadsheet. I can't seem to find any info on actually hosting the UI. Is this possible, or does it require some form of permission from Google?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to basically embed an browser control in your application pointed at the URL of a Google Apps doc? You could use the [Google Document List API](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_protocol.html) to retrieve the documents for a user, then use the URLs of those documents in your embedded browser control.

You don't need Google's permission to do that; you're writing a browser with some extra smarts built in.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Just a quick status update + maybe another hint.

I'm using the List API along with raw HTTP programming to retrieve a list of docs, and then the feed for a single doc. I then obtain what looks like a correct URI, which I then extract the document key. I do an HTTP GET on this, and specify the authentication key I got previously.

Now this sends me to the Google Docs login screen. Damn! missed something somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "hosting the UI?" These apps are HTML/CSS/JavaScript. Are you thinking about embedding them in AIR or Titanium, or in some kind of web control in another app?

Comment: Hosting in a web browser control in my app. Browsers are cool but I want to do some other things that aren't possible (yet...) in browsers.

Answer (score 0):

i briefly looked into doing this, and figured if i really wanted to i could just load the gdocs page content dynamically, and use javascript to strip away the superflous elements like header and footer.  but instead i'll probably just use an OS alternate because they have come a long way and I want rich hooks.